# How to scrape a non tabled list from wikipedia and create a datafram?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighbourhoods_of_Istanbul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighbourhoods_of_Istanbul)

in the link above, there is an un-tabulated data for Istanbul Neighborhoods.

I want to fetch these Neighborhoods into a data frame by this code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wikiurl="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighbourhoods_of_Istanbul"
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tocList=soup.findAll('a',{'class':"new"})

neighborhoods=[]

for item in tocList:
    text = item.get_text()
    neighborhoods.append(text)

    
df = pd.DataFrame(neighborhoods, columns=['Neighborhood'])
print(df)
```

and I got this output:

```
    Neighborhood
0   Maden
1   Nizam
2   Anadolu
3   Arnavutköy İmrahor
4   Arnavutköy İslambey
...     ...
705     Seyitnizam
706     Sümer
707     Telsiz
708     Veliefendi
709     Yeşiltepe

710 rows × 1 columns
```

but some data are not fetched, check the data below and compare to the output:

```
 Adalar
    
        Burgazada
        Heybeliada
        Kınalıada
        Maden
        Nizam
```

`findall()` is not fetching the Neighborhoods which referred as links, not class, i.e.

```
<ol><li><a href="/wiki/Burgazada" title="Burgazada">Burgazada</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Heybeliada" title="Heybeliada">Heybeliada</a></li>
```

**and can I develop the code into 2 columns, each  'Neighborhood' and its 'District'**

Comment: There is a wikipedia API, and a python 'wikipedia' wrapper for that API,  you might be better starting there than trying to scrape the website

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question should include an attempt at a solution. Please notice the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) the first link with the title [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fetch this list from Table of Contents ?

Please check if this solves your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wikiurl="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighbourhoods_of_Istanbul"
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tocList=soup.findAll('span',{'class':"toctext"})

districts=[]
blocked_words = ['Neighbourhoods by districts','Further reading', 'External links']
for item in tocList:
    text = item.get_text()
    if text not in blocked_words:
        districts.append(text)

    
df = pd.DataFrame(districts, columns=['districts'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       districts
0          Adalar
1      Arnavutköy
2        Ataşehir
3         Avcılar
4        Bağcılar
5    Bahçelievler
6        Bakırköy
7      Başakşehir
8      Bayrampaşa
9        Beşiktaş
10         Beykoz
11     Beylikdüzü
12        Beyoğlu
13   Büyükçekmece
14        Çatalca
15       Çekmeköy
16        Esenler
17       Esenyurt
18           Eyüp
19          Fatih
20  Gaziosmanpaşa
21       Güngören
22        Kadıköy
23      Kağıthane
24         Kartal
25   Küçükçekmece
26        Maltepe
27         Pendik
28     Sancaktepe
29        Sarıyer
30        Silivri
31    Sultanbeyli
32     Sultangazi
33           Şile
34          Şişli
35          Tuzla
36       Ümraniye
37        Üsküdar
38    Zeytinburnu
```

Comment: No I'm not trying to fetch this table.
I need to fetch the collapsed attributes of the Neighborhood i.e.: adalar>>1.Burgazda 2.Heybeliada ......

Comment: @mba_sy better create a new question with clear description.